# Insert on many to many table failing due to foreign key constraint

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have a schedule table that is created from a many to many relationship between a classes and users table.

User typeorm schema

```
@ManyToMany(type => UClass, c => c.users, {cascade: true, onDelete: "CASCADE"})
    @JoinTable({name: "schedule"})
    classes: UClass[]
```

Class typeorm schema

```
 @ManyToMany(type => User, u => u.classes)
    @JoinTable({name: "schedule"})
    users: User[]
```

When I create a user:

```
{
    "username":"a",
    ...(rest of data)
    "classes":[{"id":"f602a286-3df1-4912-9165-2375b5e45bdd"}]
}
```

I get this error:

```
QueryFailedError: insert or update on table \"schedule\" violates foreign key constraint \"FK_d796103491cf0bae197dda59477\
```

I am not sure why I am getting a foreign key error when both of the supplied (user and class) ids are both valid. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After about a day of troubleshooting I realized that the register function was working in my production version of the app and used github to backtrack what I had changed since updating production. Apparently, if you get a repository in another repository it migrates the database differently. I just had to change

```
userRepository: Repository<User>;
classRepository: Repository<UClass>;
scheduleRepository: Repository<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.userRepository = getManager().getRepository(User);
        this.classRepository = getManager().getRepository(UClass);
    }
```

to

```
userRepository: Repository<User>;
scheduleRepository: Repository<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.userRepository = getManager().getRepository(User);
    }
```